# Android - notification putExtra issue

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, android-pendingintent, extra

I've searched for about hour to find some solution how to send extras to activity when user clicks in notification box but everything I've found didn't work for me.

I need to pass event ID to activity where I show user info about this event.

I've used setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), setAction("Action"), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT and combination of all of these solution but neither didn't work.

That's my code:

```
Notification.Builder notiBuilder = new Notification.Builder(context);
                notiBuilder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.logo));
                notiBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo);
                notiBuilder.setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.eventNitificationTitle));
                notiBuilder.setContentText(obj.getString("nazwa") + " " + obj.getString("data"));

                Intent eventIntenet = new Intent(context, EventActivity.class);
                eventIntenet.setAction("Action_"+id);
                eventIntenet.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

                eventIntenet.putExtra("eventID", id);

                PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, eventIntenet, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                eventIntenet = null;

                notiBuilder.setContentIntent(pIntent);

                pIntent = null;

                NotificationManager notiManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                    notiManager.notify(Integer.parseInt(id), notiBuilder.build());
                } else {
                    notiManager.notify(Integer.parseInt(id), notiBuilder.getNotification());
                }
```

And way to get my Int:

```
this.eventID = getIntent().getIntExtra("eventID", -1);
```

Everytime when I click in notification, I'm moving to activity but getExtra returns -1.

Comment: Try getIntent().getExtra().getInt("eventID") and remove those you setting null to the Intents atleast don't set it until you finish notify.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I've done it but still didn't works. I have one question more - setting variable's value to null when I don't need it anymore is good idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something along these lines:

```
                NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ChatService.this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon)
                        .setContentTitle(senderName)
                        .setContentText("Notification Text Here");
                mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);

                Intent resultIntent = new Intent(MyService.this, TargetActivity.class);
                resultIntent.putExtra("eventID", id);

                TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(MyService.this);
                stackBuilder.addParentStack(TargetActivity.class);
                stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);

                PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

                NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                mNotificationManager.notify(id, mBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 0):

If your app is already running and your `EventActivity` is already on the top of the stack, this code:

```
this.eventID = getIntent().getIntExtra("eventID", -1);
```

will always use the `Intent` that `EventActivity` was started with **the first time.**

You should override `onNewIntent()` and get the "extra" from the `Intent` that is passed as an argument to that method.